# Toggle switch button - how to set responsive measurements?

Tags: html, css

I've created [This](https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/aaxgfqre/14/) toggle button, and i can't set it's size to percentage - so it could be responsive. i was manage to set it's text to viewport width and height - and it's working well, but i don't want the button in viewport measurements....

perhaps ::before and ::after cannot receive measurements in percentage?

Html:

```
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="material-switch">
          <input id="someSwitchOptionDefault" name="someSwitchOption001" 
             type="checkbox" />
          <label for="someSwitchOptionDefault" class="label-default"><span 
            class="homme">Homme</span><span class="femme">Femme</span>
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
      .cont {
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #e9e9e9;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
      }

      .material-switch > label {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0px;
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
        content: "\f222";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #333333;
        text-align: right;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .material-switch > label::before {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        border-radius: 16px;
        height: 24px;
        margin-top: -12px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
      }

      .material-switch > label::after {
        /*--button---*/
        content: "";
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 15px;
        height: 24px;
        left: -4px;
        margin-top: -8px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -4px;
        width: 73px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        content: "\f221";
        color: "blue";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
        background-color: #fff;
        left: 30px;
      }

      .femme {
        display: none;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label>span.homme {
        display: none;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label>span.femme {
        display: block;
      }

      .homme {
        font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #5d5d5d;
        font-size: 1vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: -8px;
        left: 9px;
        z-index: 999;
      }

      .femme {
        font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #5d5d5d;
        font-size: 1vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: -8px;
        z-index: 999;
      }

      .material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .femme {
        left: 41px;
      }

      .homme::before {
        content: "\f222";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #49c8c1;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

      .femme::before {
        content: "\f221";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #49c8c1;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
```

Comment: what is your actual requirement, I see that when I am resizing the browser window, the button is constant in size, however text inside it is zooming in and out.
Do you want button also to resize with viewport. ?

Comment: abhinav3414 - Thanks - that's exactly what i wish to achieve...but i need the button to change it's size relatively  to it's div - box_cont

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the `css` you have overridden lot of html DOM properties, like for `<input>` component. I would suggest you to use simple and elegant toggle buttons available with normal css.
You can check below **toggle button** examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch
https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/LxNxNg

Comment: abhinav3414 - Thanks - i went through your examples..but the structure is very similar to mine...both are manipulate the input's DOM....